# Do more expensive bib shorts make a difference when sat on a turbo trainer for hours on end?

Tags: turbo-trainer

Several times during the year I occasionally have to work night shifts (mostly during winter). This can make longer training sessions difficult as the shifts which allow this type of training ride (+2 hours) that are not days off finish at 1:00am. Going out training at this time in the morning can be fun but I more often than not hit the rollers (deer, drunks and potholes). I would like to get in longer rides this coming winter but am finding sitting on rollers for more than one hour and a half painful. Would a 'top of the range' pair of bib shorts designed for long distance (assos s7) riding help ease the pain?

Comment: A liberal helping of chamois-cream and rule #5 ;)

Comment: Bib shorts may or not make a difference, but the chamois might.But you realise the only way you'll find out for sure is to go buy a pair? You mention Assos, which is an excellent brand but also expensive. Consider also Etxeondo, if you can obtain them. Similar quality (at least I think so) and cheaper. I speak as someone who owns a fair amount of Assos kit but who now buys Etxeondo where possible. Difficult to get hold of though.

Comment: if you do go for assos, check out www.assosfactoryoutlet.com but I still think it's expensive

Comment: I've found quality shorts make a bigger difference on outdoor rides. At home I use which ever shorts are clean at the time and whilst the fancy ones are more comfortable to wear, fit better etc., there's not a lot they can do to stop my bum going numb. This is most likely a personal thing though, not everyone's riding or nether regions are the same.

Answer (score 2):

The big difference between rollers and the outside is that your position is much more static inside. If you are good enough on rollers to stand every once in a while that might help. ( I'm not ). Maybe just take a 5 minute break every hour.

If your shorts/saddle are comfortable outside for 2+ hrs, I doubt expensive shorts will really make much of a difference. However, when it comes to saddle comfort everything works for somebody and nothing works for everybody.

I'd try the expensive Assos cream to start with, it's only a $30 experiment vs a $300 one.

Answer (score 0):

To be perfectly honest it MIGHT help but if you're wearing decent shorts and can't stand 1.5 hours in the saddle then you just need to get through it and do more hours. I find that after a few weeks off the road bike, it takes a few rides for me to get used to being back in the saddle constantly on a ride (as opposed to less frequently on MTB).